# How to stretch div inside DevExpress' Callback panel with horizontal scroll bar?

Tags: html, css

We have MVC 5 application where we use a lot of DevExpress and DevExtreme components. On the left side we have DevExpress's Navigation Bar and on the right is content area controlled by its Callback panel. In the screen shots attached you can see the whole picture and the right part of content area. The green and grey divs are on top of content area and they don't stretch when we make the browser's window smaller. In that scenario the horizontal scroll bar automatically appears and when we scroll to the right green and grey divs don't stretch.

The code looks as following:

1) HTML:

```
<div class="dashboard-sub-title">Расчет потерь электроэнергии</div>

<div class="dashboard-parameter-box">
    <div id="FieldsList" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block"></div>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
    С:&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id="StartDate" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block"></div>&emsp;
    По:&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id="EndDate" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block"></div>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
    Период:&nbsp;&nbsp;<div id="DateTimePeriod" style="vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block"></div>&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;
    <div id="ShowButton"></div>
</div>

<div class="dashboard-content">
    <div id="DataGrid" style="margin-left: 5px; vertical-align: top; display: inline-block"></div>
    <div style="border: 1px solid #d3d3d3; width: 800px; vertical-align: top; display: inline-block;">
        <div id="RealLostDonutChart" style="width: 400px; vertical-align: top; display: inline-block;"></div>
        <div id="NormativeLostDonutChart" style="width: 400px; vertical-align: top; display: inline-block;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="LineChart" style="border: 1px solid #d3d3d3; margin-top: 5px; margin-left: 5px; width: 1505px; height: 450px;"></div>
</div>
```

2) CSS:

```
.dashboard-sub-title {
    min-width: 1200px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(41, 213, 0, 0.59);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    text-align: center;
    font: 15pt Arial,sans-serif;     
    font-weight: bold;
}

.dashboard-parameter-box {
    min-width: 1200px;
    padding: 5px;   
    margin-bottom: 5px;   
    background-color: #e7ecf0;     
    font: 8pt Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

As you can see dashboard-sub-title and dashboard-parameter-box are responsible for divs' behavior what I'm talking about.

How it looks like:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think its **not necessary** to add **min-width** in the css for dashboard-sub-title and dashboard-parameter-box.

Just set the percentage widths for the leftsidebar and the right content area which includes both dashboard-sub-title and dashboard-parameter-box.

Just like the below code for example::

```
.left-sidebar {width: 30%; float: left;}
.right-content {width: 70%; float: right;}
```

and then no min-widths for the inner divs::

```
.dashboard-sub-title {
  /* min-width: 1200px; */
}
.dashboard-parameter-box {
  /* min-width: 1200px; */
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it's a complex mix of DevExpress MVC controls, HTML and CSS.